# Spritekit - Rotate a SK3dNode along its y axis

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have 3D star in spritekit and have it rotating along z axis so it looks like its spinning.

However I cannot get it to spin. 
The file is a `.dae` file which I have imported into my project. 
The star itself loads but nothing happens. Any idea anyone?

```
import SpriteKit

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let starScene = SCNScene.init(named: "star.dae")
    let star3d = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 330, height: 330))
    star3d.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    star3d.scnScene = starScene
    star3d.zPosition = 3
    star3d.isPlaying = true
    star3d.scnScene = starScene

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    camera.xFov = 60
    camera.yFov = 60

    var cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4Make(1, 2, 3, .pi * 2))
    rotationAnimation.duration = 6
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX

    starScene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    star3d.pointOfView = cameraNode
    self.addChild(star3d)

    cameraNode.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

Comment: If you are rotating on z, is a SK3Dnode even needed?  Do you mean you are rotating on the y axis?

Comment: ahh yes, rotating on the y axis. I will change the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly set `star3d.pointOfView` to the camera, but you haven't added `cameraNode`to the scene.

```
starScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

Here's a complete version, in a macOS playground. Swap out the last two lines (`current.liveView`) to see the raw SceneKit render or the combined SpriteKit render.

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let spritekitView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 500))
let scenekitView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 500))

let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 320))
spritekitView.showsFPS = true
spritekitView.presentScene(spriteKitScene)
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = spritekitView

// let starScene = SCNScene.init(named: "star.dae")
let starScene = SCNScene()
starScene.rootNode.addChildNode(SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 1, height: 2, length: 3, chamferRadius: 0.2)))

let star3d = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 330, height: 330))
star3d.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.frame.midX, y: spriteKitScene.frame.midY)
star3d.scnScene = starScene
star3d.isPlaying = true
spriteKitScene.addChild(star3d)

let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.xFov = 60
camera.yFov = 60

var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 3, z: 15)

starScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

star3d.pointOfView = cameraNode
scenekitView.scene = starScene
scenekitView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
scenekitView.pointOfView = cameraNode

let rotateVector = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, CGFloat(2 * M_PI))
let rotate = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0.0, y: 0, z: CGFloat(2 * M_PI), duration: 10.0))
cameraNode.runAction(rotate)
let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
rotationAnimation.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: rotateVector)
rotationAnimation.duration = 6
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
//cameraNode.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = spritekitView
//PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = scenekitView
```

Comment: okay that works and I can see the movement of the star in the simulator iPhone 6 however on a iPhone 6 device, there is no movement. Any idea why?

Comment: right, so I had to add PrefersOpenGL = Yes to the project.plist list and the animation on the device worked. One final question. the star is not spinning correctly. Needs to spin vertically so it looks like a spinning star. I thought just changing the y axis would do it....

Comment: In SceneKit, you're looking down the -Z axis. Spin the camera around its Z axis.

Comment: tried but does not do anything.         rotationAnimation.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 3, 0))

Comment: That's a 0 rotation around the Z axis. Try SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 3, M_PI).

Comment: nope doesnt work. Now that i think about it. The animation is applied to the cameraNode and not the node itself. When I run a test on a .scn file and add a action to rotate the y axis on a 3d node. It works and the star spins. Could it be the cameraNode position is wrong? cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 3, z: 15)

Comment: It's more likely that your star isn't where you think it is. Back away, and get just the SCNView working correctly, with a simple geometry primitive like a box or pyramid. Then use your DAE file. Then put the SCNScene back in the SK3DNode. I modified my answer to do a rotation around the Z axis, and it works with SCNAction and with Core Animation.

Comment: Thanks, will accept your answer. Just fyi. this is the animation I'm after hence query about the camera node. http://media0.giphy.com/media/rOhH4D15SlWCc/giphy.gif

Comment: That would have been helpful to see a few hours ago! Suggestion: instead of moving the camera, find the star  (`childNodeWithName:recursively`) and rotate it.

Comment: No luck. Gave the SK3dNode a name of "star3d" and tried the following.         let starNode = starScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "star3d", recursively: true)
........ let rotate = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0.0, y: 4, z: 0, duration: 3.0))
        .........starNode?.runAction(rotate)

Comment: Figured it out by playing with the cameraNode settings. The exact effect i wanted. Thanks for your help mate. Had to use usesOrthographicProjection setting on the camera node.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hal Mueller.
The following spinning star effect can be achieved with the below code adding a sk3dnode into spritekit.

[media0.giphy.com/media/rOhH4D15SlWCc/giphy.gif](http://media0.giphy.com/media/rOhH4D15SlWCc/giphy.gif)

If the animation does not run on your device. 
In your project .plist file add the following row.
PrefersOpenGL = YES

```
let starScene = SCNScene.init(named: "Round_CStar_obj.obj.dae")
    let star3d = SK3DNode(viewportSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
    star3d.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
    star3d.scnScene = starScene
    star3d.name = "star3d"
    star3d.zPosition = 3
    star3d.zRotation = 6
    star3d.isPlaying = true
    star3d.scnScene = starScene
    self.addChild(star3d)

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
    camera.orthographicScale = 9
    camera.zNear = 0
    camera.zFar = 200

    var cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    starScene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    star3d.pointOfView = cameraNode

    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "rotation")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = NSValue(scnVector4: SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi * 2))
    rotationAnimation.duration = 2
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
    cameraNode.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
```